# SQL: How to exclude group from result set by one of the elements, not using subqueries

Tags: sql

Input:

```
id    group_id    type_id    
1     1           aaaaa          
2     1           BAD
3     2           bbbbb
4     2           ccccc
5     3           ddddd
6     3           eeeee
7     3           aaaaa
```

1. I need to output `group_id`s which consist only of a members for which `type_id <> 'BAD'`. A whole group with at least one `BAD` member should be excluded
2. Use of subqueries (or CTE or `NOT EXISTS` or views or T-SQL inline functions) is not allowed!
3. Use of `except` is not allowed!
4. Use of cursors is not allowed.

Any solutions which trick the rules above are appreciated. Any RDBMS is ok.

Bad example solution producing correct results, (using `except`):

```
select distinct group_id
from input
except
select group_id
from input
where type_id = 'bad'
group by group_id, type_id
```

Output:

```
group_id
2
3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group by `group_id` and count occurrences of `'BAD'`:

```
select group_id
from mytable
group by group_id
having count(case when type_id = 'BAD' then 'count me' end) = 0;
```

Answer (score 4):

I would just use `group by` and `having`:

```
select group_id
from input
group by group_id
having min(type_id) = 'good' and max(type_id) = min(type_id);
```

This particular version assumes that `type_id` (as in the question) does not take on `NULL` values.  It is easily modified to take that into account.

EDIT:

If you are looking for one bad, then just do:

```
select group_id
from input
where type_id = 'bad'
group by group_id;
```

Comment: I guess I asked the wrong question, in my real case `type_id` may take any value (not null) but only one value is bad. The answer is still awesome though.